# Why can we choose the wavefunction to be real in the absence of a magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have seen it written on multiple occasions that if we consider a situation in which we have an uncharged particle or a charged particle in the absence of an external magnetic field, it is possible to choose the wavefunction of the particle to be real. I was wondering why this is? Is it somehow related to our freedom to choose a gauge transformation which renders the wavefunction real?

Comment: could it be that it is because in the absence of external magnetic field the system is time-reversal symmetric? and in that case $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ should have the same energy?

Comment: The only redundancy of the wavefunction is its phase. And in a square well, harmonic potential or anything else, there are plenty of wavefunctions that cannot be made real by any phase. Did you perhaps mean to say this about energy eigenstates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing down the eigenvalue equation $H\Psi=E\Psi$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian, should answer your question. In the case of no magnetic field you can take the complex conjugate of that differential equation and discover that it is the same equation, just with $\Psi^*$ instead of $\Psi$. So the complex conjugate is also a solution. This means any linear combination of $\Psi$ and $\Psi^*$ is also an eigenfunction with the same energy and $\Psi+\Psi^*$ is real.

This argument fails when a magnetic field is involved because $H$ in that case contains terms proportional to $i A\nabla$ and $i \nabla A$ (where $A$ is the vector potential) which do in fact change when taking the complex conjugate because they contain $i$.

If you are wondering where these terms are coming from please look up the Hamiltonian for a charged particle in a magnetic field. For the case of no further potentials the Hamiltonian can be found for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization) and in the general case you just add a (real) potential.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That makes sense. The only thing I was wondering about is what Connor Behan mentions above. This argument seems to only apply to energy eigenstates - I guess that it is not possible to render a general state real?

Comment: My question here would be "what do you mean by rendering a general state real?". Connor Behan is completely correct: That's not possible. The thing I did was argue that we can always find a real eigenstate. This eigenstate might look different from the eigenstate we started with. So we didn't "render it real", but we found a real alternative that keeps the property of being an eigenstate. So if you want to do that with another state you must first say what property you want to keep.